# Sequelize Node.js new functions not working after creating a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, node.js, model, sequelize.js

So I have two models, User and Chat. Each User can have multiple chats and each chat can have multiple users. So I created a new model called UserChat -

```
var db = require('../db');
var Chat = require('../models/chats');
var User = require('../models/users');


var UserChat = db.connection.define("user_chat", {
    id: {
        type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    }
})

Chat.ChatModel.belongsToMany(User.UserModel, {through: {model: 'user_chat'}});
User.UserModel.belongsToMany(Chat.ChatModel, {through: {model: 'user_chat'}});
```

This creates a table in my database called user_chats and according to sequelize's documentation, I should be able to use addUser on my Chat model and addChat on my User Model,

But when I try to use Chat.ChatModel.addUser(user) I get the error "addUser is not a function"

This is how I declare the Chat Model and User Model -

```
var db = require('../db')
    var Chat = db.connection.define("chat", {
        chatname: {
            type: db.Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        creator:{
            type: db.Sequelize.INTEGER,
            unique: false,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });

    module.exports.ChatModel = Chat;
```

and then my User model (simplified) -

```
var db = require('../db')

var User = db.connection.define("user", {
    username: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: false,
        allowNull: false
    },
});

module.exports.UserModel = User;
```

Now if I try to use the addUser function or any new function I should be given according to the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongsto) I get the error that the function still doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

So my problem was I was trying to call the methods on the actual models, but the methods get added to instances of the models. So you need to find the chat/user before using the addChat or addUser on it.